# Serialize an array with item id in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2008, serialization

I have an array e.g.

```
Float[] flObj = new Float[]{1.2, 2.3, 3.5};
```

to be able to serialize this object, I make a class FloatArray and have the constructor like this:

```
[Serializable]  
public class FloatArray
>{  
....
public float[] _arrSetPoint;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
        public float this[int idx]
        {
            set
            {
                if (idx >= 0 && idx < _arrSize)
                    _arrSetPoint[idx] = (float)value;
                else
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
            get
            {
                if (idx >= 0 && idx < _arrSize)
                    return _arrSetPoint[idx];
                else
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
}
```

When I serialize this class, I got:

```
<flObj >  
 <float> value=1.2</float>  
 <float> value=2.3</float>  
 <float> value=3.5</float>  
</flObj >
```

How can I get the following xml?

```
<flObj >
 <float.0> value=1.2</float>
 <float.1> value=2.3</float>
 <float.2> value=3.5</float>
</flObj >
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second version is not valid XML and cannot be output using the .NET built in serializers.

You can write your own [custom serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675.aspx) to output the exact format you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you used a dictionary with the int as the key and serialized that, you would capture something like what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why you're creating your own array type here rather than just creating a fixed-size array instead.

```
float[] a = new float[10];
```

Also, I recommend learning LINQ - it's beauty and expressiveness will just blow you away:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace SerializeFloatArray
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a fixed-length array of floats:
            float[] a = new float[10];

            // Initialize the array to contain some content.
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                a[i] = float.Parse(i.ToString() + '.' + (i + 1).ToString());
            }

            // Create an XML document containing XML elements named as you require.
            int j = 0;
            var doc = new XDocument(
                new XElement("floats",
                    from f in a
                    select new XElement("f." + j++.ToString(), f)));

            // Display doc serialized to text. You could write this to a 
            // file if you want.
            Console.WriteLine(doc);
        }
    }
}
```